# Use the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions to find the optimal solution

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

> Use the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions to find the optimal solution to the following non-linear programming problem.
> $$
> \begin{gathered}
> \min z=\left(x_{1}-1\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-2\right)^{2} \\
> \text { s.t. }-x_{1}+x_{2}=1 \\
> x_{1}+x_{2} \leq 2 \\
> x_{1}, x_{2} \geq 0
> \end{gathered}
> $$

I followed [this](http://www.apmonitor.com/me575/uploads/Main/kkt_example3_solution.pdf) site to solve this problem,

> Note: at the optimum, it is known that the inequality constraint is satisfied but not
> binding. Take advantage of this information.

**Question:** I couldn't understand the note mentioned that site.

Dropping the inequality constraint, we get,

$$
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{2x_1-2\\2x_2-4}-\lambda_1\pmatrix{-1\\2}&=\pmatrix{0\\0}\\
\pmatrix{2x_1\\2x_2}+\pmatrix{\lambda_1\\-2\lambda_1}&=\pmatrix{2\\4}
\end{align}
$$

Use the equality constraint $-x_1+x_2+0.\lambda_1=1$,

$$
A=\pmatrix{-1&1&0\\2&0&1\\0&2&-2}\quad b=\pmatrix{1\\2\\4}
$$
$$
\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\\lambda_1}=A^{-1}b=\pmatrix{1\\2\\0}
$$

Hence, the $z_{\min}=(1-1)^2+(2-2)^2=0$.

---

But the solution provided in my textbook was $z_{\min}=\frac12,x_1=\frac12,x_2=\frac32$. Did their procedure is wrong? I used that because it seems short. But now it wasn't giving the exact solution.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that $x_1 + x_2 = 1+2 \not \le 2$. So your dropping of the inequality constraint led to a non-admissible solution

Comment: So, is there any check before I apply this procedure? @Lukas. And could you explain what was meant by **"at the optimum, it is known that the inequality constraint is satisfied but not binding. Take advantage of this information."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information given to you is wrong. The inequality is binding as we can see that the circle touches the halfspace.

[image]

To make use of your working, you can assume that you were considering the case where it is not binding and you found a contradiction. Hence we know that it is binding, now you can solve the problem by solving $-x_1+x_2=1, x_1+x_2=2$.

Comment: Aha, thank you, @SiongThyeGoh. It will save my life. The traditional way is so much computation. Thanks again(+1).